# Flash CS6 publishing for Android

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, apk

Using Flash CS6 I've created and installed an .apk file on my phone. When I try to launch it, this error occurs:

> The application appname (process air.appname) has stopped
>   unexpectedly. Please try again.

I used the "Embed Air runtime with application" option while publishing.

Comment: At this point, it could be just about anything. Your best bet is to retrieve the error using LogCat. You'll need to hook your phone up to a computer that has the Android Debug Bridge (ADB--it's part of the Android SDK) installed.

Comment: Use try catch blocks in your air application. Check for support of used  apis. Check included files in build. As Blumer say it could be just about anything.

Comment: On Galaxy s3 it works fine. Seems like Wildfire S does not support it

Answer (score 2):

I've tested on AVD level 10 - intall Runtime.apk and MyApp.apk - Successful runned MyApp, but on AVD level 15 (using ARMv7a) - The application appname has stopped unexpectedly.

To run flash app.apk of flash cs6 on AVD for the first time on Windows:

1. Create and Run AVD with ARMv6 (Ex: AVD Level 10; < level 15)

2. Find and Connect to your device using command: adb devices

2. Install runtime.apk using: adb install "your\flash\runtimes\air\android\emulator\runtime.apk" (ex: "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS6\AIR3.2\runtimes\air\android\emulator\runtime.apk")

3. Create and install YourApp.apk on AVD Level 10 as installing runtime.apk

4. Go to AVD and run YourApp on App pane.

Answer (score 1):

Not only does the version of Android you are running have to support Adobe Air (Android 2.2 or later),but your phone has to have the ARMv7 processor, not ARMv6. I think that is the most common problem. Look up what processor your phone has.